# How to go to the beginning of a word/sexp?

Tags: navigation, words, sexp

When the point is not at the beginning of a word/sexp, `backward-word / backward-sexp` places the cursor at the beginning of that word/sexp. If the point is already at the beginning of a word/sexp, this is of course not the case.

How to go to the beginning of the current word/sexp regardless of the point position?

**Edit 1**: By current sexp, I mean the smallest sexp containing the point, for example if the cursor is at `o` in the expression `(end-of-line)`, the current sexp would be `end-of-line`. If the cursor is at `(`, the current sexp would be the whole `(end-of-line)`.

**Edit 2**:
 Another reformulation of this question: *how to detect if the point is at the beginning of the current word/sexp?*

Comment: Do you mean if the point is already at the beginning of sexp it should stay where it is if you call backward-sexp?

Comment: @hatschipuh A function which puts the cursor at the beginning of the current word/sexp. Of course, `backward-word/sexp` itself cannot do this.

Comment: Essentially, one would need to test for the various known conditions -- e.g., a space before the word or at line beginning. This can be done various ways -- e.g., regexp test; using a syntax test; testing for certain character codes; etc. Here is an example of a custom function that tests using syntax:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489  It is just an *example*, which is *not* custom tailored to answer this particular question.